# Problem with HTML DOM selecting everyhing but one element JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have been trying to for hours now to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596664/close-a-block-by-clicking-outside-it-but-taking-into-account-the-element-except/62598393#comment110702418_62598393):
And I can not wrap my mind around it.

This open/closes menu on click when click on button :

```js
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('ul .header_content_one_menu')) {
    $('ul .header_content_one_menu').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#header_menu_adaptive {
  display: none;
}


html, body {
    margin: 5;
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.05s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  visibility: visible;
  
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 28px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_content_one_menu {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #B72A20;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  content: '';
  bottom: 29px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.header_content_one_menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox">
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>меню</span>
</label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">111</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">222</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">333</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">444</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">555</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">666</a></li>
</ul>

<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This closes menu when clciked anywhere outside of list (but not the button)

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) && $(".header_content_one_menu").has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
```

```css
#header_menu_adaptive {
  display: none;
}


html, body {
    margin: 5;
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.05s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  visibility: visible;
  
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 28px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_content_one_menu {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #B72A20;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  content: '';
  bottom: 29px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.header_content_one_menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox">
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>меню</span>
</label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">111</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">222</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">333</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">444</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">555</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">666</a></li>
</ul>

<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read every single SO article around here and also  [jquery tree-traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) and I can not figure out why this two cancel each other out. I have tried with all above selectors from CSS and jquery Tree Traversal's, it  seems impossible to combine this two, or written this in some simple way (question has working answer but seems like overkill).

I stubble upon this and it makes no sense to me, I would really appreciate if someone would explain  what is going on (I would like to know, not my code or problem).

Clicks do register on every element, so no problem with z-index's from CSS, I tried to re-write this in so many ways, it fells i tried everything.

To make it short:
why i can not have all 3 conditions from this two examples combined in one if? Hide menu when clicked on close button or outside of menu (but not ul items).

So why is this for example not working (when clicked outside of menu items):

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (
   $("label  .header_menu_adaptive_button:not(.header_content_one_menu *)").is(e.target) ||
    !$("ul .header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) &&
    $("ul .header_content_one_menu").has(e.target).length === 0
    ) {
    $('ul .header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
#header_menu_adaptive {
  display: none;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.05s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
  visibility: visible;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  visibility: visible;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 28px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked~.header_content_one_menu {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before,
.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #B72A20;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button>span::before {
  content: '';
  bottom: 29px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.header_content_one_menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox">
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>меню</span>
</label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">111</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">222</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">333</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">444</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">555</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">666</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why don't you use toggle method to switch?

Comment: @xenon it doesn't react on body click, everywhere but element. that's the main problem, or its reacting only to button.

Comment: Have you seen that when you right click it on the second snipe it does close?

Comment: @Carlos1232 wow you are right! Whats that about! But it reacts to right click anywhere

Comment: If you right click on the X it close too, its a weird behavior; guess it have to do something with the DOMElement it self.